# How i can get all substring of size k of string?

Tags: c++, string

I don't know where is the error in my code ? can someone help me to fix it .

My code :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
void solution() {
   string s;
   ll k;
   cin >> s >> k;
   for(int i=0; i<=s.length()-k; i++) {
       for(int r=k-1; r<s.length(); r++){
           cout << s.substr(i,r) << endl;
       }
   }
}
int main() {
    ll t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
         solution();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input :

```
1
ABCD 3
```

Expected output:

```
ABC
BCD
```

Actual output:

```
AB
ABC
BC
BCD
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I'm voting that `#include<bits/stdc++.h` is where an error is in your code.  The include file is not standard C++; but a specific of a special compiler.

Comment: BTW, if you need to define abbreviation macros, you should invest in some keyboarding classes.  In professional programming, that coding style is frowned up and may get you fired.

Comment: If this is *competition* programming, you should assign `s.length` and `s.length - k` to constant temporary variable.  The expression will be evaluated (executed) for each iteration, unless you have a smart compiler and set the optimization level accordingly.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? What does it do instead? Please show a [mre] with inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs

Comment: @Alan Birtles I want to print all substring exactly of size k.

Comment: What does it do instead? Please show a [mre] with inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs

Comment: @Alan Birtles and now .

Comment: is the output the expected output or the actual output?

Comment: actual output .

Comment: OK, so what's the expected output?

Comment: what do you mean by expected output ?

Comment: if your code was working correctly what do you expect it to print?

Comment: this output is expect output  , but the actual output is : AB - ABC - BC - BCD

Comment: Trying scrolling down. I get the correct output.

Comment: @Captain Hatteras can put it like as answer .

Comment: If you only want a single size of output why do you have a second for loop that varies the string size?

Comment: i did't understand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you need a nested for loop. Why isn't this just simply:

```
void solution() {
   string s;
   ll k;
   cin >> s >> k;

   for(int i = 0; i <= s.length() - k; i++) {
     cout << s.substr(i, k) << endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get all substring with the length given:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    int input = 0;
    std::string str = "";
    std::cin >> input >> str;    //This is the length of substring you wanna get
    for (int i = str.size() - input; i >= 0; i--){
        std::cout << str.substr(i, input) << " ";    //output the result from end to begin
    }
}
```

No checking for empty input. Correct input will output a decreasing-order answer.